# What are the handling effects of converting a dihedral wing to polyhedral?

Tags: wing, model-aircraft, remote-pilot

I'm looking at plans to build a radio controlled (RC) glider that is launched by rocket boost mainly as a park flyer. I've been given a set of plans for a model that is a dihedral wing (see attached photo), and I am thinking converting it to a polyhedral wing, as I read that polyhedral wings are more stable for people new to flying as I am.

The new wing shape (I haven't drawn it out yet), would have a flat section over the fuselage acting as a partial cover for the rc components, then a 6 degree angle from there to mid point of the wing, and then another 6 degree angle to the tip.

Wing length and total angles/measurements would be the same, as would the airfoil (Which can be seen in the rib segments on the plan). My other option is simply adding the central flat fuselage cover section, and leaving the rest of the wing as is. (One note, the reason for the thinning of the rib sections in the front is that it is a partially built wing, there is a balsa skin over those parts, then the entire wing is coated in a lightweight monokote type material).

Is there any value in making this change to a polyhedral wing, or is it mostly a wasted effort that I shouldn't worry about doing?

Wing section (I have full plans if other angles are desired):
[image]

Comment: Ever break in the wing requires reinforcements since the spars and sheeting are cut. This increases weight and complexity. Just build it as designed.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of in-flight behavior, the biggest change between dihedral and polyhedral (or tip dihedral) with the same overall stability is more roll response for a given yaw input -- this occurs because yaw-induced roll is caused by the skid presenting the outside wing at a higher angle of attack than the inside, and this effect is both more pronounced, per area, with the sharper angle of a tip dihedral or polyhedral tip panel, and is applied further from the centerline, so has a longer lever arm.

I'd agree, however, with the advice in another answer, not to modify your first kit.  Build to plans and instructions.  If you want to compare, get the kit built and the model flying correctly, then either buy another kit or buy materials (make photocopies or scans of the ribs and tip plates) and build another wing -- then you can compare the in-flight behavior for yourself.

Comment: Yaw is movement around the vertical axis, so if I translate correctly, a poly wing will produce sharper turns and greater roll? So a simple dihedral wing is a "genter" handling characteristic?

Comment: @JohnP almost correct.  A poly wing will produce more *roll* than simple dihedral, other factors equal.  Higher bank, coupled with some elevator input, *can* produce sharper turns, but the more usual use case is to give usable levels of bank from a smaller rudder or less deflection.

Comment: so... net effect for a new flyer who will likelier have a heavy touch on the controls would be a "twitchier" handling model with a poly vs di.

Comment: Depends.  Poly and tip dihedral are used on trainers -- but with small rudders and low flight speed (because poly recovers to level very positively).  A twitch at rocket boost speed, and you're likely to rip the wings off.

Comment: Raising the wing tips higher may drastically affect the frontal center of drag, by raising it above the center of gravity.  Especially for a rocket aircraft this could be absolutely disasterous. Look at the X-15.  You want symmetry and plenty of stability.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni the tips would remain at the same height.

Comment: @ZeissIkon for most rocket boost, there is not really any adjustment during the (1-3 secondish) boost phase. And all control is usually in the tail section, there aren't too many rocket boost gliders that have ailerons in the wing. But I see what you are saying.

Comment: @JohnP you may have to trim a little elevator down (tail upforce) for the rocket boost to keep it from looping.  See how it glides first, then start with the smallest rocket motor (Estes 1/4A3), or a good hard throw from a hill.  After boost, reset to glide trim.  You may find relevant info in "discus throw launch style" gliders. You may find it flies great without modifications.  Good luck!

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni - That's the plan, actually. Start with a "dart" type throw and see how the flight works. Then gradually work up to higher throws (discus launch) and work on just circling back to me, getting used to the RC aspect. Once that is decent, then work on low power launches. I'm also meeting with a local RC club at their next gathering to ask n00blet questions.:)

Comment: @JohnP Dihedral, and especially poly or tip dihedral, is sometimes called "nature's ailerons".  A little yaw is just like a lot of aileron input.  At very high speed, one twitch on the rudder (usually mapped to the right stick for rudder-elevator models without actual ailerons) and the roll forces generated may break the wing spar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are "new to flying" please do not start out by making modifications to your kit.  Build it faithfully and to the letter as best you can.  Secondly, rocket power may be too much for now.  Take your model to a good hill and learn to glide it first.

Changing a dihedral to a polyhedral will only make your build more difficult.  Biggest issues will be control throws and setting the CG correctly, followed by crosswind performance, which could be seriously affected by modifications.  Stick with the plan.

It is highly recommended to find a "mentor" at a local R/C flying club, or even to join one.
This will save many crashes, which end hours of building in seconds.  Expect a few during the learning process.

Comment: Useful advice, and it answers the question embedded at the end, but it doesn't answer the title question.

Comment: @Michael Hall really too many to mention, and impossible to quantify without testing.  IMHO not a good idea for someone "new".

Comment: Maybe not a good idea for a new builder, (as you pointed out) but for a new flyer?  The OP stated "I read that polyhedral wings are more stable for people new to flying as I am."  While admitting to being new at flying, he might be very accomplished at fabrication.  In this case the added stability (if true) would be a definite plus, right?

Comment: @Michael Hall yes, as a glider, added stability would be a plus, as a rocket plane, no.  It is very important to have frontal drag, CG, and thrust going through the same point on a rocket (just look at the ones with out wings).  I would also worry about cross wind effects and frontal drag change doing these mods.  Raising Cdrag would negatively affect handling by increasing pitch up tendency, but could be an interesting substitute for tail downforce if done right.  But I would follow the plan first.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni - Realize that the rocket boost will be in the order of 1-3 seconds at a max load of 10 newtons. I realize that disaster takes less than a second (Believe me, I've had my share of spectacular launch failures on new design rockets), but the actual "rocket plane" segment is very short and almost exclusively for altitude. I anticipate around 4-700 feet on an average C/D engine.

Comment: @JohnP big difference between a C and a D (1/4 A probably made you laugh).  See DLG videos on net.